# How can I make this weaved pattern more realistic?

Tags: texturing, materials

First I apologize for making a kind of similar question to the one asked 6 hours ago. I still feel the need to ask another question because I've successfully modeled the weaved pattern and now I would like to ask about the node setups in Blender to make it more bamboo like.

After apply some color to it, the pattern looks like this:

[image: Chair]

Needless to say, it looks completely fake, although I tweaked some settings in the Principled BSDF node. I have three questions:

1- Why does my texture look very fake? I can clearly see it looks fake, but can't explain why.

2- Can we use some node setups only in Blender to achieve the bamboo texture? Or must we use some bamboo texture image?

3- If we can use node setups only, what is it? I'm experimenting with noise texture to add roughness on the surface, but achieve no significant result.

I would like to achieve this texture:

[image]

My blend file: [Chair.blend](https://filebin.net/15qqj6s6ug827a16). The pattern is on layer 2.

Comment: With regards to your model looking fake. First it lacks additional shape detail you should be using look into [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tce6GqNyJ2A) by 
GarageFarm.NET Academy. Next material detail will help i'm sure there are several videos about creating procedural wood textures here is one [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRCrFaqoHMY) by Chris Ebbi.

Comment: @Ratt: Thanks a ton, Ratt. I will check those tutorials.

Comment: Everything looks fake with unnatural lighting. HDRI environment can help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should work on the texture. You can do it procedurally (for example mixing some *Wave* node textures) but the easiest way to do it is to use a repeatable wood image texture. Then you can duplicate this material and vary the color with a *Color* > *Hue/Saturation* node. Don't forget to put a bit of glossiness at the end.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, moonboots! I'll try this.